Summer 24 Flow New Feature - Reactive Collection Choice Sets
Summer 24 Flow New Feature - Reactive Collection Choice Sets
I was trying the new flow feature (Update Choices on a Screen in Real Time with Reactive Collection Choice Sets) to make Collection Choice Set resource reactive. Any idea how can I make the output of datatable component to populate a collection choice set resource?
My use case is -
DataTable showing all the Accounts, when user will select an account from there, I would like to show the list of contacts under that account as choice lookup by using Collection Choice Set. Somehow the collection choice set is not working / reacting based on DataTable selection change. Any idea?

Are you using the unofficialsf Datatable component?  If you use it, the selected sObject collection can be passed into the reactive version of the Collection Processors. Another option is to leverage Data Fetcher
Just note that there's a Known Issue where the formula SUBSTITUTE() function only performs the operation 1x, so you can't easily swap ";" or "," to "','" for use in SOQL In ('a','b') statements.  fix deploying Summer 24
